# Subscript Out of Range Error :9

Tags: vba, excel

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim wkbk As Workbook
Dim NewFile As Variant

NewFile = Application.GetOpenFilename(FileFilter:="Microsoft Excel Files 
(*.xlsx; *.xls), (*.xlsx; *.xls), All Files, *.*", FilterIndex:=1)

If NewFile <> False Then
Set wkbk = Workbooks.Open(NewFile)
End If


Worksheets("Sunday").Unprotect "bunny"

Dim Sh As Worksheet
For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Sh.Visible = True Then
        Sh.Activate
        Sh.Cells.Copy
        Sh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
        Sh.Range("A1").Select
    End If
Next Sh
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Worksheets("Sunday").Protect "bunny", True, True


Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Hello, pretty knew to VBA, can do tiny thing in it. I'm trying to make something which allows you to select an excel file to open, opens it, un-protects the sheet "Sunday", pastes over the data, re-protects, then saves and closes the document.

The main bit of code works on my current sheet if I don't include the portion to open a file, but when I am trying to use it on the workbook I have just opened, I am getting a 'Subscript out of range' error message. I am not too sure if I am the newly opened file is 'active', but when I tried insert a line of vba to make the new document active, it made no difference. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Try `wkbk.Worksheets` instead of `Worksheets` or `ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets`. Try to find out at which line the error occurs.

Comment: Two things, both of which shouldn't give you an "out of range" error (unless the workbook you open doesn't include a sheet called "Sunday") - (a) You would be better off if you used `wkbk.Worksheets("Sunday")` instead of just `Worksheets("Sunday")`.  The current method relies on the opened workbook being the active workbook, which **should** be the case but, because users are very unreliable, may not be.  (b) Your loop is processing all the sheets in `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets` - did you want that, or did you want `wkbk.Worksheets`?

Comment: Correction to the last bit. My error has changed now, and it only seems to surround the following section.
    'Dim Sh As Worksheet
    For Each Sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        If Sh.Visible = True Then
            Sh.Activate
            Sh.Cells.Copy
            Sh.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
            Sh.Range("A1").Select
        End If
    Next Sh
    Application.CutCopyMode = False'    Where I am getting a application defined or object defined error. I cannot also work our how to do code in comments :(

Comment: Resolved the issue. Does anyone know how I could then go about saving and closing this workbook?

Comment: (a) Re your "I cannot also work our how to do code in comments" - you can't do any meaningful code in comments, and you probably shouldn't - that's what the "edit" link under the question is for.  (b) `wkbk.Close True` should close the workbook, saving the changes.  Or `ThisWorkbook.Close True` if you want to save and close the workbook that contains the macro - which seems to be the one you are updating.  (Of course, closing `ThisWorkbook` will then stop the macro, so it will possibly be more appropriate to just use `ThisWorkbook.Save`.)